# A limit about $\prod_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{1-x^k}$

Tags: calculus, analysis, asymptotics, generating-functions

If $$\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {{a_n}{x^n}}  = \prod\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{1 - {x^k}}}} ,$$ Prove $${a_n} < \exp \left\{ {\sqrt {\frac{{2\pi }}{3}n} } \right\}$$ and $$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{{n{a_n}}}{{\exp \left\{ {\pi \sqrt {\frac{{2n}}{3}} } \right\}}} = \frac{{\sqrt 3 }}{{12}}.$$

I have no idea! Please show me how to solve it, thanks!

Comment: You have no ideal or no idea? :-)

Comment: @OttavioConsone no idea,haha!

Comment: You know this is the [Partition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29#Partition_function), right?